# Camera movement in OpenGL ES android

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

I am very confused about the use on GLU.gLookAt(eyeX,eyeY,eyeZ,Xpos,Ypos,Zpos,upX,upY,upZ) method. All I want is to zoom the 3d cube. 
When I increase/decrease value of eyeZ, the camera moves forward/backward to the cube. Its all fine up to a certain limit of eyeZ, but when I increase the eyeZ value beyond that limit, it starts reverting the effect i.e. instead of zooming in it starts zooming out.

I might not be good in openGL to understand above method but could anyone tell me whats the basic reason behind this.
I referred to this link
http://jerome.jouvie.free.fr/opengl-tutorials/Tutorial8.php

If you want I can post my code over here..

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();


    //gl.glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, -zoomFactor);
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeZ, eyeZ, 0f, 0f, 0f  , 0f, 1f, 0f);

    gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, -1, 0, 0);

    // Draw the model
    cube.draw(gl);
}
```

this is the method where i am using gLookAt method..

Comment: do post your code, and the point at which it starts to zoom out

Comment: Well, if you move the camera along the line, at one point you are the closest to your target.

Comment: public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
   
     gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
     gl.glLoadIdentity();
    
      
     //gl.glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, -zoomFactor);
     GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeZ, eyeZ, 0f, 0f, 0f , 0f, 1f, 0f);
 
     gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 0, 1, 0);
     gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, -1, 0, 0);
      
     // Draw the model
     cube.draw(gl);

   }

Comment: Please don't post blocks of code as comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: sorry.. I didn't knw hw to do that..

Answer (score 1):

`GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeZ, eyeZ, 0f, 0f, 0f  , 0f, 1f, 0f);` is a function that puts your camera looking at a particular spot, in this case its (0,0,0) (i think, cant remember which way round the parameters are, but im assuming the last 3 are your up vector). So if you move your camera towards what you are looking at, eventually it will go through it and out the other side, and since you are using `GLU.gluLookAt` it will turn to face the object behind it, thus giving you the impression that you are zooming out when you carry on moving in the same direction.

Comment: yes.. You are right.. So what can I do to avoid it.. I mean to make sure that camera should not turn to face the object from its behind

Comment: you will have to stop using glulookat. you will need to rotate your camera using glrotate to face it in the direction you want , then use gltranslate to move it into the position you want (or translate first then rotate, usually the order of events are backwards)

Comment: or you could use glulookat, and move its look at point by the amount you are moving forward ie `GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeZ, eyeZ, 0f, 0f, (startEyeZ - currentEyeZ) , 0f, 1f, 0f);` not sure if that is right, but something to that effect (also are you sure you are meant to have 2 `eyeZ`'s in the parameters of that function?)

Comment: @VishalTavande or you could `lookAt` `[0,0,1]` from `[0,0,0]`, then translate the camera where you want it

Comment: @Fonix Actually the function is misprinted. There are no teo eyeZ's instead the function is GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, 0f, 0f, 0f , 0f, 1f, 0f); Sorry.. I used glTranslate(x,y,-zoom) it is working well but my requirement is to move the camera instead of moving that object. Hope u got it

Comment: well actually, there is no notion of a camera in opengl, to move the 'camera' you move everything in the scene. ie, do translates/rotations that will effect every other object you render from then on. this would be more apparent if you were doing opengl 2+

Comment: @Fonix so is there any difference in glTranslate() and gLookAt() method, as I came to know that there is no much difference among them in android openGL ES

Comment: ye essentially you can make glulookat using translations and rotations yourself, its just a helper function really.